# How do I find calling method in debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I use Visual Studio 2008 for a C# project. I have trouble debugging a specific method:

```
public override DataStateInformationType UpdateMetaDataStatus(DataStateInformationType dataStateInformation)
```

It is being called a bunch of places and I would like to know which method is invoking UpdateMetaDataStatus. Where can I see this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will appear in the call stack window.

While debugging:

```
Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack
```

Or, by default:

<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + C</kbd>

Comment: Excellent. This was exactly what I was looking for. I can accept the answer in 5 minutes:-)